# Calculate the total price of items in an invoice

Tags: php, sql, pdo

## here is what I have:-

```
accountid    |    productname     |   qty    |   price       |    companyexported   |
8            |    name            |    5     |    50         |         company1     |
8            |    name2           |    5     |    60         |         company1     |
8            |    name3           |    10    |    10         |         company2     |
```

this is the basket table and I'm sorting each item by companyexported (Bill)
so I want to calculate the total cost for the bill ( the sum(price) of the all the same value (companyexported) row that contain the same company name and of course order by accountid
what I have tried:- 
Code:-

```
$price = $PDOCon->prepare("SELECT SUM(price) AS totalprice FROM basket WHERE accountid ='$accountid' order by companyexported");
$price->execute();

$row = $price->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['totalprice'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the sum per company, you need to `GROUP BY companyexported`, not `ORDER BY`. Note that as long as you are preparing a statement, you should use placeholders for parameters:

```
$price = $PDOCon->prepare("SELECT SUM(price) AS totalprice
                           FROM basket
                           WHERE accountid = :accountid
                           GROUP BY companyexported");
$price->bindParam(':accountid', $accountid);
$price->execute();
```

Also since you will get multiple results (one for each company), your fetch should be in a loop:

```
while ($row = $price->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['totalprice'];
}
```